# TV show or movie with monster stealing things in big house

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I grew up in Sweden in the 90s, so this could well be a European/Swedish dubbed children's TV-show/movie.

The story is about a family moving into a big house/apartment building and noticing that things start  disappearing from their home. They suspect burglars, but it turns out to be some kind of monster doing the stealing.

There is one scene in particular where the protagonist (a child) is in a cramped area with lots of boxes, possibly an attic. The child is lecturing the monster, which is very large and clumsy, possibly with colorful fur (blue? green?). I don't remember anything else about the nature or result of this confrontation.

Note: this is not the movie *Little Monsters* from 1989 which also features a (more humanoid) monster with bright blue fur.

Comment: Do you mean the child is the protagonist not antagonist? What is the child lecturing the monster about? How did they end up meeting, the child stumbled across it? Do any of the other family members know of it? What's the conclusion? Monster friends with family? Monster leaves? etc. If you remember anything else about this you can [edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot thank you for the correction regarding protagonist/antagonist. I don't have any other information other than what I wrote unfortunately. Its possible that the child speaks some sense into the monster but it's not something I remember